# Evenly sized columns between rows using grid/flex

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

Consider the following snippet:

```css
#container{
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">A1111</div>
    <div class="item">B1</div>
    <div class="item">C1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">A2</div>
    <div class="item">B2222</div>
    <div class="item">C2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">A3</div>
    <div class="item">B3</div>
    <div class="item">C3333</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The end result is a table-like display where each item of every row is the width of the widest item in that column.

```
A1111 A2    A3
B1    B2222 B3
C1    C2    C3333
```

Which is great - but I need the table laid out as rows...

```
A1111 B1    C1
A2    B2222 C2
A3    B3    C3333
```

`display: table` solves this - but table has some drawbacks around spacing, alignments and so-on. Therefore, grid and flex looks attractive.

Alas I cannot figure out how to get the information laid out as desired.

Adding `display: grid` to `.row` helps the order of information, but doesn't retain the equal column widths.

The item content will vary, and so cannot use fixed widths and it is not desired that the grid/flex spans the entire page/containing width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define which column the grid item should be using grid-column. This means the row doesn't require a containing row div.

Working example...

```css
#container{
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col1{
  grid-column: 1;
}

.col2{
  grid-column: 2;
}

.col3{
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="col1">A11111</div>
    <div class="col2">B1</div>
    <div class="col3">C1</div>
    <div class="col1">A2</div>
    <div class="col2">B2222222</div>
    <div class="col3">C2</div>
    <div class="col1">A3</div>
    <div class="col2">B3</div>
    <div class="col3">C33333333</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. (Would have been helpful in your question if you mentioned that the HTML could be altered.)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is your markup is too deep. You have table-like markup, three levels deep: table, rows, and cells. For grid layout, you don’t need the “row” elements at all.

When you use `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid` on an element, it makes that element a *grid container*. Each of its child elements then become *grid items*. Grid items will be laid out in the grid defined by their container.

You also said you want columns of equal width. For this, you should use the `fr` unit rather than `auto` for your column sizes:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

…this will make each column one “fraction” unit wide.

```css
#container{
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">A1111</div>
  <div class="item">B1</div>
  <div class="item">C1</div>
  <div class="item">A2</div>
  <div class="item">B2222</div>
  <div class="item">C2</div>
  <div class="item">A3</div>
  <div class="item">B3</div>
  <div class="item">C3333</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's way which I would make it.

[Attached JSFiddle(click)](https://jsfiddle.net/2uajcz2b/)

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row > .item {
  display:block;
  flex: 1 1;

  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

There's such great guide about `flex`; [Click here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Yes, I have been referring to that guide a lot. This is great, however the flex spans the entire width, and therefore too much spacing. The items are of unknown length, so cannot set fixed widths.